# jQuery - Different Select

Tags: jquery, select

I have two HTML select boxes. The first is called #1 and the second is called #2.

Whenever I take an option in #1, #2 select box should only show valid options that are linked to the option I took at #1 select box, and so on.

How is this possible?

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: @user: By removing the invalid options from select #2 when an item in select #1 is chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called cascading list or "dependent select list". Take a [look at this article](http://www.ajaxray.com/blog/2007/11/08/jquery-controlled-dependent-or-cascading-select-list-2/) which demonstrates a way to implement it.